# Can I connect a wall switch to DC?

Tags: switches, fan, dimmer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx7YHr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am making an air blower with a Kingwin RL4B-B1402512H fan. Can I use the wall switch, and if so, can I use the dimmer as well?

Comment: You can't use the dimmer. The wall switch should work in this case but only because the DC current is so very very very low compared to the AC current rating of the switch. Normally the DC current rating of a switch is much much lower than the AC current rating for the same switch.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The dimmer requires 120VAC to work. The fan needs 12VDC.

This fan could be controlled with a 2-wire speed control, [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P2BLG2L). Or, consider a different 140mm fan with 4-wire control, and connect a PWM speed controller to it.